# importing a rdc file into Blender gets an error

Tags: import

I am wondering if anyone here can help with an issue relating to plug-ins. I have successfully added these plug-ins, and I understand that they work as there are several people on YouTube who are using them without any problems.
My question is; I get an error when I try to import a RenderDoc file (rdc) Blender is telling me that the captured file is an ‘Invalid RDC render file’. I have tried Blender 2.83, and have tried the latest version. I have also downloaded the latest version for both RenderDoc, MapModelslmporter v3.70, and MSFSToolkit v0.40 still no joy.
What I am trying to achieve is to import 3d files from google maps, then take the converted snap-shot pictures, which are saved as a .rdc then import them into Blender.
Has anyone attempted this, or has anyone done something similar? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BlenderGIS can import earth maps live from blender, which may be more effective.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, the only thing is I can not get the 3d textures from the screen grab.